# Android get correct size of button

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to retrieve the size of my button but it return wrong size. The text of my button is variable.

I retrieve the button width like that :

```
button.getWidth()
```

But it says 420px even if I set a larger text.
How can I get the correct size?

I have already tried to use `addOnLayoutChangeListener`, it worked but in te onlayoutchange function I could not update the UI.

Comment: Maybe you added the button with width=match_parent, so it will never change, if you added with wrap_content the getWidth() should return the correct value. Also, at onCreate or just after LayoutInflater.inflate the button with a relative size (wrap,match) will have width = 0, so if you set 420px on code and are checking in the places i commented it will always be the same value. try to print the value in the click of the button.

Comment: You are rigth, On the onclick listener the size is correct. In wich function should I retrieve the correct width?

Comment: In the onLayout of some custom component that you make that is the parent of button, so after super.onLayout you can get the measured width with int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(button.getMeasuredWidth())

Answer (score 0):

override `onWindowFocusChanged`

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    int w=button.getWidth();
    Log.d(TAG,w);
 }
```

Comment: I am in a fragment, I do not have acces to this function.